# Where is my firewall?

Tags: linux, firewall, linux-mint, iptables

Using Linux Mint 17 and logged in as root...

When I enter the command

```
more /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

I get the error

```
/etc/sysconfig/iptables: no such file or directory
```

When I enter the command

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

I get the error

```
bash: /etc/sysconfig/iptables: No such file or directory
```

Since Mint is based on Ubuntu, I imagine it has "ufw" which I thought meant Unbuntu Firewall, but apparently it means "uncomplicated firewall" to set iptables rules. 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFir...

For `locate iptables`, my computer shows in the terminal:

```
/sbin/iptables
/sbin/iptables-apply
/sbin/iptables-restore
/sbin/iptables-save
/usr/bin/iptables-xml
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/backend_iptables.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/__pycache__/backend_iptables.cpython-34.pyc
/usr/sbin/iptables-apply
/usr/share/iptables
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/iptables
/usr/share/doc/iptables
/usr/share/doc/iptables/INCOMPATIBILITIES
/usr/share/doc/iptables/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/iptables/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/iptables/copyright
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-1.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-10.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-11.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-2.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-3.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-4.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-5.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-6.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-7.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-8.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO-9.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/NAT-HOWTO.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-1.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-10.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-11.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-2.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-3.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-4.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-5.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-6.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-8.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO-9.html
/usr/share/doc/iptables/html/packet-filtering-HOWTO.html
/usr/share/iptables/iptables.xslt
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/iptables
/usr/share/man/man1/iptables-xml.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/iptables-apply.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/iptables-extensions.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/iptables-restore.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/iptables-save.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/iptables.8.gz
/usr/share/mime/text/x-iptables.xml
/usr/share/ufw/iptables
/usr/share/ufw/iptables/after.rules
/usr/share/ufw/iptables/after6.rules
/usr/share/ufw/iptables/before.rules
/usr/share/ufw/iptables/before6.rules
/usr/share/ufw/iptables/user.rules
/usr/share/ufw/iptables/user6.rules
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-32-generic/include/config/ip/nf/iptables.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-32-generic/include/config/ip6/nf/iptables.h
/var/lib/dpkg/info/iptables.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/iptables.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/iptables.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/iptables.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/iptables.shlibs
```

I also entered `sudo updatedb` into the command line to no avail.

My goal is to configure the firewall to allow SSH.

Comment: Linux Mint uses UFW by default.  You should try enabling it with `sudo ufw enable`.

Comment: @Julie Pelletier But if I want to allow SSH, should I disable it?

Comment: Why ask how to enable something you don't want?  Please clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try `iptables-save > dump`, where `dump` is an iptables dump file in the current dir.

`/etc/sysconfig` is specific for Red Hat based distros therefore you got errors.